# Extending Pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, panel, time-series

I'd like to expand a pandas timeseries when updating with new data. Here's how I'm creating the initial Panel, for stock data. Here's the initial empty panel:

```
def create_blank_data():
    dates = pd.date_range(start=dt.date(2008, 1, 1), end=dt.date.today())
    attrs = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
    symbols_ = symbols.read()
    data = np.zeros((len(symbols_), len(dates), len(attrs)))
    return pd.Panel(data, items=symbols_, major_axis=dates, minor_axis=attrs)
```

I can then populate the initial data like this:

```
def test_fresh_data():
    data = create_blank_data()
    for symbol in symbols.read():
        data[symbol] = api(symbol, start='2010-01-01') # returns a Dataframe.
    return data
```

This seems to work, but, I'm unable to extend the data. If any of the dataframes I load contain newer data, I'd like to update the panel. Currently, if I update the panel using another "data[symbol] = api(symbol, start='2010-01-01')" line, data with a newer dates than is defined in the panel is ignored. My thought it to explicitly expand the panel's date range first.

I've been using [this page as reference.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html)

Comment: It's not going to be easy to answer this one without some sample data and an explanation of what `symbols` and `api` are. You should also explain whether the new data you are updating with overlaps with the existing data.

Comment: 'symbols' are short strings such as 'GOOG' and 'AAPL'. api retrieves an up-to-date dataframe from the internet. Example: data['GOOG']['Close'][dt.date(2013, 1, 2)] retrieves Google's close price on Jan 2, 2013. I'm leaning towards the answer to this being "there is no easy way to add to the major/minor axes of panels, or add rows to dataframes"

Comment: The new data does overlap with the existing data; I'd like to update only the non-overlapping data. A short-term solution is just replacing the old data with the updated data.