# Extending a pandas panel frame along the major (timeseries) axis

Tags: python, pandas, panel, time-series

I have some time-series data which is stored in a slightly strange format. I want to parse it into a `pandas.Panel`

The data come from various 'locations'. Data from each location are contiguous in the file but the time series from any given location is split into separate 'chunks'. There should be no overlap between the time-chunks for one location.

I have been reading each location-time-chunk into a `pandas.Panel` with:

- `Item axis = location`
- `Major axis = DatetimeIndex`

I'd like to extend the `Panel`'s axis to accommodate any new chunks of a location's time axis.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# we'll get data like this from the file
time_chunk_1 = pd.date_range(start='2010-10-01T00:00:00', periods=20,
                              freq='10S')                                  
fake_data = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(time_chunk_1)))                                  
mars_data_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=fake_data, index=time_chunk_1,
                    columns=['X'])                    
pluto_data_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=fake_data, index=time_chunk_1,
                    columns=['X']) 

# gather the data in a panel
planet_data = pd.Panel(data={'Mars': mars_data_1, 'Pluto': pluto_data_1}) 

# further down the file we'll encounter data like this
time_chunk_2 = pd.date_range(start='2010-10-01T00:03:20', periods=20,
                              freq='10S')                                  
mars_data_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=fake_data[::-1], index=time_chunk_2,
                    columns=['X'])    

# I can make a DataFrame of the whole Mars time-series                   
mars_data_all =  planet_data['Mars'].append(mars_data_2) 

# but setting a frame of the panel doesn't extend the major axis
planet_data['Mars'] =  mars_data_all
```

After I've collected the chunks, I'd like the following to be true:

```
planet_data.Mars.index is mars_data_all.index
```

I've tried permutations of:

1. setting a new frame in the panel (`planet_data['AllMars'] = mars_data_all`)
2. `pandas.Panel.reindex`
3. `pandas.Panel.replace`

It seems like I'm maybe getting confused between the underlying data and views on it. I've looked a these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203437/extending-pandas-timeseries), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364050/extending-a-pandas-panel-frame-along-the-minor-axis)) related questions but I'm still stuck. It feels like I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works, for some value of 'works'. I didn't have the rep to answer my own question quickly so this answer 1st appeared as a comment.

This works:

```
planet_data = planet_data.reindex(major_axis=mars_data_all.index)
planet_data['Mars'] = mars_data_all
```

in the sense that it passes:

```
assert(0 is all(planet_data.Mars.X - mars_data_all.X))
assert(planet_data.Mars.index is mars_data_all.index)
```

For a significant dataset, I suspect we would run into the hashtable not getting garbage collected issue raised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18074101/3751373). There is probably a better way of doing this.

The real life the data turn out to be much bigger, hairier and more misaligned than those in my example code. So much so, that `reindex`ing will not work.

I'll probably end up using a `dict` of `DataFrames` rather than a `Panel` as my outer data structure.